# Installation directory for Wordpress and child theme

Tags: child-theme, directory, installation

I'm very new to WordPress.  I've read a common problem beginners make is installing in the wrong directory.  Could someone verify mine is installed correctly?  I'd like to use Storefront theme with Boutique child theme.

```
    Host1/mydomain/public_html/wp
    Host1/mydomain/public_html/wp-admin          
    Host1/mydomain/public_html/wp-content (contains themes/boutique & themes/storefront)
    Host1/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no "correct" directory structure.   One of the great strengths of WordPress is how many options exist for configuration.   Tricks like using a local [config file](http://wanderingjon.com/2013/06/16/wordpress-local-development-tips/), for example, allow you to work in so many different ways.

That being said, what you have outlined is a very standard file structure and should suit you just fine.

If you do not want the /wp/ portion of your file system in your site URL, take a look at [Giving WordPress its own directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Comment: Well no wonder I'm confused.  Thanks for the answer and the link

Answer (score 0):

Child theme would be located in: /wp-content/themes/child-theme-here. To make it clear too, this would be the same path as the parent theme, all the themes sit in the themes folder at the same level.

Your current layout looks correct for a WP installation.

How did you do your WP installation, was it from a service like Fantastico or did you do it manually? If done manually the contents of your WP version download (from wordpress.org) should have just been moved to your website folder. You could always download another copy of WordPress and view the structure on your desktop to see if your site is correct.

Also woothemes has pretty good documentation for you to refer to if you have any questions, here's part of one for installing [Boutique child theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/boutique-storefront-child-theme/#section-1), and here for [installing Storefront](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/installation-configuration/).

Comment: I'm using BlueHost so I installed using their "Install WordPress' in cPanel.